# Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, generics, generic-collections

What does it mean? I used a list of list in ASP.NET MVC and sent them through `ViewData` of `ActionResuls` to retrieve it in views.

However, when I change it to list of list, it gives me an error of `HttpWebException`. When I check it inside the immediate window, it tells me that the error is:

> Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments

So, what does it mean and what did I do wrong using it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `List<T>` class is a generic type.

In order to use it, you need to provide a type argument.

For example, if you want to have a list of integers, you need to declare it as `List<int>`, not `List`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wrote something like `List<List>> ...`
But there is no class named List.. - List has a generic type parameter.
For example - list of lists of integers should be

```
List<List<int>> listOfLists = .....
```

For better understanding of C# generics take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to just use `using System.Collections.Generic;` to get access to lists.

Answer (score 0):

I was simply missing a semicolon ";" at the end of the line :)