# How to call a method with List type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

I would like to call a method whose type is `List`. I'm working with C#.NET + MVC 4.

### The problem

I am a beginner and I do not understand the following error:

> **Error** 1 Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' requires 1 type arguments

### What I have

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content(getProductsList(0, 14));
    }

    public virtual List getProductsList(int isOffer, int categoryId)
    {
        List data = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery("CALL getProductsListForHome({0}, {1});", isOffer, categoryId).ToList();

        return data;
    }
```

What I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: List is a generic type -- you could use `List<object>`, or better, `List<YourEntityType>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223102/using-the-generic-type-system-collections-generic-listt-requires-1-type-argu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is a [generic type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) that means that its implementation takes a “wildcard” type `T` and when an object of the type is created, that type `T` is substituted by whatever you want to keep in the list.

For the list, this means that you store objects with the same type within the list, and when retrieving elements from the list, they still have that type.

Examples of valid declarations of such lists are the following:

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>();
List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>();
```

In your case, you are using [`ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) which is a generic method taking a type parameter itself. The choice of that type parameter decides of which type the `List<>` should be. You didn’t specify a type for the method call yet, so if you fix the list declaration, this would probably be the next error you get.

Ideally, it should be something like this:

```
List<Product> data = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Product>("CALL getProductsListForHome({0}, {1});", isOffer, categoryId).ToList();
```

Btw. I’m not sure but I think you use `ExecuteStoreQuery` wrong. First, the parameter placeholders are very likely not string formatting placeholders but SQL placeholders (`@1`, `@2`), and second, it seems that the method just wants the name of the *stored* query. So you would call it like this:

```
ExecuteStoreQuery<Product>("getProductsListForHome", isOffer, categoryId).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello, @poke. Thanks about your entry. You said "You didn’t specify a type for the method call yet, so if you fix the list declaration, this would probably be the next error you get.". You are right — I get the error. How can I "fix" it? What is the solution?

Comment: See the example code line below that. In short you need to specify the generic parameter in the method call too: `ExecuteStoreQuery<Product>` – between the `<>`.

Answer (score 1):

`List` is a generic type, which means that it must include type parameter `T`: `List<T>` e.g. `List<int>` or `List<YourClass>`

Answer (score 0):

You need a datatype for your List like so:

```
public virtual List<Product> getProductsList(int isOffer, int categoryId)
{
    List<Product> data = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery("CALL getProductsListForHome({0}, {1});", isOffer, categoryId).ToList();

    return data;
}
```