# System.Collections.Generic.List<T> requires '1' type arguments

Tags: c#, list

I have this error whith the following code:

```
string[] colors = { "green", "brown", "blue", "red" };
var list = new List(colors);
IEnumerable query = list.Where(c => c.length == 3);
list.Remove("red");
Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
```

Moreover, `Count()` does not seem to be allowed anymore. Is it deprecated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223102/using-the-generic-type-system-collections-generic-listt-requires-1-type-argu)

Comment: colors.ToList() wouldn't work for you?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are trying to create a `List<string>` and you should tell that to the compiler

```
var list = new List<string>(colors);
```

There is no `List`, there is a *generic* class named [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), requires a type parameter.You can't create a generic list without specifying the type parameter.

Also you are trying to call `Count` extension method.That method takes `IEnumerable<T>` as first parameter,not `IEnumerable`, here is the definition:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
```

so you should use `IEnumerable<string>` to access that extension method:

```
IEnumerable<string> query = list.Where(c => c.Length == 3);
list.Remove("red");
Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, so it is a **generic** list, therefore you must provide the **generic parameter** `T`. In your example case, you want a `List<string>`. So try:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(colors);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need a `List` at all in your sample and you can simplify everything a lot:

```
var count = new [] { "green", "brown", "blue", "red" }
    .Where(c => c.length == 3)
    .Where(c => c != "red")
    .Count();
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] colors = { "green", "brown", "blue", "red" };
    var list = new List<string>(colors); // <string>
    IEnumerable query = list.Where(c => c.Length == 3); // "Length", not "length"
    list.Remove("red");
    Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
}
```

Comment: @DGibbs Did you forget about "System.Linq.LinqExtention.Count(this IEnumerable)" ??? Please be sure 101% about something before DownVote someone!

Comment: I am 100% certain. You've defined a non-generic `IEnumerable`... I suspect you want `IEnumerable<string>` if you intend to access the `Count();` method, alternatively, you can call `Cast<T>` providing the type e.g. `list.Cast<string>().Count()`. Please be `101%` sure your code is correct before answering a question.

Comment: @DGibbs I have written and successfully tested it on Visual Studio. Only then I have posted the answer. You are logically right. But the fact is that the code works fine in VS. So would you please correct me where is my fault?

Comment: `I have written and successfully tested it on Visual Studio.` I seriously doubt that. Learn the difference: [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) vs [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx).