# Using the generic type System.Collections.Generic.List<T> requires 1 type arguments

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, generic-collections

i upgraded my application .Net Framework version from 3.5 to 4.5.1 and also i changed the targeted version from 3.5 to 4.5.1. my application using Linq to SQL.. in my application i am using Class Library and in class library i need to pass multiple parameters in Generic list...

In Data Access Layer i have method where i am trying to pass a multiple class that generated by Linq to Sql. (tblaccount, vendorCategory)

```
internal class BasicDataDAO
{

  internal List<tblaccount, vendorCategory> GetAllvendor()
    {
       using (CommonDataContext VendorDC = new CommonDataContext(Settings.ConnectionString))
         {
             VendorDC.DeferredLoadingEnabled = true;

             return (from V in VendorDC.tblaccounts
                    join C in VendorDC.vendorCategories on V.CatID equals C.Vendor_CatID
                            where V.Sys_AC_type == 7
                            select new
                            {
                                V.ID,
                                V.ACCOUNT,
                                V.field2,
                                V.contactDetails,
                                V.Remarks,
                                V.field3,
                                V.field1,
                                V.email,
                                V.fax,
                                C.vendor_CategoryName
                            }).ToList();           
                }
            }
}
```

here how i am handling this in Business layer

```
public List<tblaccount, vendorCategory> GetAllVendors()       
{
            BasicDataDAO dao = new BasicDataDAO();
            return dao.GetAllvendor();            
}
```

but i am getting this error in both Data and Business Layers

> **Using the generic type System.Collections.Generic.List requires 1 type arguments**

how to achieve this task, in which you can pass multiple classes generated by linq in Generic List?

although i have upgraded .Net Framework from 3.5 to 4.5.1 but still i am not able to reference the System.Tuple class in my Class Library

Comment: Related, but not exact duplicate (I think): [Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223102/using-the-generic-type-system-collections-generic-listt-requires-1-type-argu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot declare list with two type arguments.

You can use `Tuple<T1, T2>` instead: `List<Tuple<tblaccount, vendorCategory>>` or create your own class with 2 properties.

But looking at your code, it looks like you're trying to return anonymous type instance as method result. That's not what anonymous types are for:

> **You cannot declare** a field, a property, an event, or **the return type
>   of a method as having an anonymous type**. Similarly, you cannot declare
>   a formal parameter of a method, property, constructor, or indexer as
>   having an anonymous type. To pass an anonymous type, or a collection
>   that contains anonymous types, as an argument to a method, you can
>   declare the parameter as type object. However, doing this defeats the
>   purpose of strong typing. **If you must store query results or pass them
>   outside the method boundary, consider using an ordinary named struct
>   or class instead of an anonymous type**.
>
> *from [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)*

Follow the guidelines and create your own class to hold results of your query, and declare method as `List<MyClass>`.

Comment: hi @MarcinJuraszek what if is use iqueryable to return an anonymous type please see my answer and tell me if this trick would create any problem or not

Comment: @SiddiqBaig You can return that as non-generic `IQueryable`, but you looks type safety while accessing results.

Answer (score 0):

**use iQueryable Class to return an anonymous type**

```
public IQueryable GetAllvendor()
        {
            CommonDataContext VendorDC = new CommonDataContext(Settings.ConnectionString);
            {
                VendorDC.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

                var List = (from V in VendorDC.tblaccounts
                            join C in VendorDC.vendorCategories on V.CatID equals C.Vendor_CatID
                            where V.Sys_AC_type == 7
                            select new
                            {
                                V.ID,
                                V.ACCOUNT,
                                V.field2,
                                V.contactDetails,
                                V.Remarks,
                                V.field3,
                                V.field1,
                                V.email,
                                V.fax,
                                C.vendor_CategoryName
                            });

                return List;
            }

        }
```

**and on the calling site**

```
 public IQueryable GetAllVendors()
        {

            BasicDataDAO dao = new BasicDataDAO();
            return dao.GetAllvendor();
        }
```