# Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' requires '1' type argument(s)

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, generic-collections

I have an assignment to create a "Tweeter" app in c#, and for some reason I can't get it to do the most simple thing, add items to a list and display them.

I keep getting the error:

> Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' requires '1' type argument(s)

on the following line of code:

```
List tweets = new List<Tweet>();
```

I tried doing

```
Tweet tweets = new List<Tweet>();
```

first, but it gave me over a dozen errors.

Here's my Tweet.cs:

```
namespace Assign3_Twitter
{
    public class Tweet
    {
        public string HashTag { get; private set; }
        public string Message { get; private set; }
        public string Sender { get; private set; }
        public string Recipient { get; private set; }
        public Tweet (string sender, string message, string hashtag, string reciepient)
        {
            this.Sender = sender;
            this.HashTag = hashtag;
            this.Message = message;
            this.Recipient = reciepient;
        }

        public override string ToString ()
        {
            return string.Format ("[Tweet: HashTag={0}, Message={1}, Sender={2}, Recipient={3}]", HashTag, Message, Sender, Recipient);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's where I'm having all the issues:

TweetManager.cs

```
namespace Assign3_Twitter
{
    public class TweetManager
    {
        private List tweets = new List<Tweet>();

        public TweetManager()
        {
            tweets = new List<Tweet>();

            Tweet tw1 = new Tweet ("Austen", "Hello World!", "#Hey", "Twitter");
            tweets.Add (tw1);

            Tweet tw2 = new Tweet ("Test1", "Hello World! x2", "#Howdy", "Tweeter");
            tweets.Add (tw2);

            Tweet tw3 = new Tweet ("Test2", "Hello World! x3", "#Hey", "Twitter");
            tweets.Add (tw3);

            Tweet tw4 = new Tweet ("Test3", "Hello World! x4", "#Howdy", "Tweeter");
            tweets.Add (tw4);

            Tweet tw5 = new Tweet ("Test4", "Hey there!", "#Hey", "Twitter");
            tweets.Add (tw5);

            Tweet tw6 = new Tweet ("Test5", "Woah this is cool!", "#Howdy", "Tweeter");
            tweets.Add (tw6);
        }

        public void SeeAllTweeters()
        {
            foreach (Tweet Tweets in tweets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (Tweets);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223102/using-the-generic-type-system-collections-generic-listt-requires-1-type-argu)

Answer (score 13):

```
List tweets = new List<Tweet>();
```

should be

```
List<Tweet> tweets = new List<Tweet>();
```

In the first line you're trying to assign a typed list to an untyped list.

Also, as [Kirk points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022394/using-the-generic-type-system-collections-generic-list-requires-1-type-argum#comment37028716_24022421), simply using `var` instead of declaring the type yourself would automatically use the type that you intend:

```
var tweets = new List<Tweet>();
```

Comment: Either that or just `var`.

Comment: You can also declare `tweets` as an interface type, as [TyCobb](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24022622/456814) pointed out in his answer. Some of the common types used are `ICollection`, `IEnumerable`, and `IList`.

Comment: Note that `var` is not allowed for a field (class-level variable). It could seem that the asker has a field, in which case the full type must be given.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out.... you need to declare it as `List<Tweet>` or use `var`. `var` will automatically be turned into the correct type at compile time.

Now I am not sure if this is a simple mistake in forgetting to declare the generic or if you thought you just needed to declare `List`.

`List` doesn't actually exist. If you were looking to use something more generic, you could choose any of the interfaces on the `List<T>` that has the functionality you wanted. For instance, you could have used `IList`, `IList<T>`, `ICollection`, etc.

Setting your `new List<Tweet>()` to any of the interfaces above would have worked out as well.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you have to do

```
List<Tweet> tweets = new List<Tweet>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either specify the full type (including the generics):

```
 List<Tweet> tweets = new List<Tweet>();
```

Or use implicit typing:

```
 var tweets = new List<Tweet>();
```